# shorten or control the length of url link in org mode without bitly packages

Tags: org-mode, emacs24.4, hyperlinks

I have very long url,  for example,  https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCGM8KgUXqsS4d8-4rgWRWKg/playlists, how can I tailor it into a shorter form?

Like : https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC... [here ... means there are still content here]
Remarks:

1. There is a package called *bitly*, but I don't want to use;
2. I do know this [[link][description]] stuff, I just want to display url.

Anyone has any ideas? Thanks!!!

Comment: It seems that this web just render my link the way I wish in org-mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So this may not be exactly what you want but it turns the section that is underneath your point into a link that should be shorter.

```
(defun compress-org-link (arg)
  (interactive "P")
  (let ((url (thing-at-point 'url))
    (bounds (bounds-of-thing-at-point 'url)))
    (kill-region (car bounds) (cdr bounds))
    (insert (format "[[%s][%s]]" url (truncate-string-to-width url (if arg (prefix-numeric-value arg) 40) nil nil "...")))))
```

You can change the constant 40 to be a more suitable url length default. You can also feed the function a prefix arg to set the length of the final string.

Comment: I tried this function, it transform the original to [[][]] form, with the truncated link being the content of second []. this is good start. But the original link is automatically rendered my emacs. It seems the transformed link is NOT linked to the right place. Any this provide a new perspective. Thanks!

Comment: Oh yes I see what I did wrong. It should be better now, I was grabbing the symbol instead of the url at the point. Let me know if this fixes your problem!

Comment: Yeah, It worked! Thank you so much! It just make long url in org mode in a very brief form:)